# Is there a way to open the channel dialog directly instead open ShareSheet first then the channel dialog?

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I have a requirement to display limited channels (e.g. facebook, twitter, instagrm) for users to choose from my app and need to open the corresponding channel directly instead going to the system's share sheet first then channel dialog. Wondering is there a way to achieve this by using Banch API?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Branch Android SDK does not have a method to directly share the content on a third party channel. However, you can use Branch to [create a deep link](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#create-deep-link) and then use the channel's SDK or a WebView to directly show a share dialog.